# Why't merge LineNumberReader into BuffredReader in Java?

Tags: java, io

We know!!

LineNumberReader extends from BuffredReader, LineNumberReader is  very a little mothods, some methods, Why't merge LineNumberReader into BuffredReader in Java ? it is easy for learning ??

Some one can tell main reason, Java designer do it?

Comment: Someone vote down, but don't say something?

Answer (score 1):

Because `LineNumberReader` has methods that aren't necessarily applicable to `BufferedReader`.